# How can I call a function on a different thread using C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I'm creating a component that will be consumed by other teams / products. The component allows client code to issue a set of commands, and internally these commands are executed on a worker thread - with a thread safe queue implementation where the commands are added to the queue on the callers (clients) thread, and removed / processed on the worker thread.

I'd like to provide feedback from my component to the client code, in the form 'operation XYZ has completed'. I can easily do this via callbacks, however the callback is called on my worker thread - I'd like it to happen on the callers (clients) thread. **How can I do this?**

It's a cross platform component (Windows, Linux, OS X). Boost is available. My default development compiler is MS VC++ 2010, i.e. it's not C++11.

Comment: What happens to the client thread after the commands are queued? Do you block it, or do you return to the caller? If the thread is blocked, it's easy, otherwise quite hard.

Comment: @MSalters, we don't block - we return to the client ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to arrange this type of multithreaded architecture is for each thread to have a blocking queue of functors.

Each thread loops over its queue, executing each functor in turn.

To call a function in a different thread you simply create and add a functor to that threads queue.

To create functors in C++ you can use `std::function` and `std::bind`, lamdbas, function objects or function pointers.  See `std::function`

There is no standard blocking queue, but it is fairly easy to write one with a semaphore and a mutex (which are part of `std::thread` library afaik, and also part of pthread).  Google for `"blocking queue"`

Comment: That looks very helpful, but is unfortunately C++11 specific. Is a none C++11 solution available? I've updated the question to reflect this need.

Comment: All of that can be done with `boost::function`, `boost::bind` and `boost::thread` if `boost` is available but C++11 is not.

Comment: @Chad, could you be more explicit? Perhaps with a simple example?

Comment: sdt::function/boost::functionares just a nice storage class for functors and function pointers. There's no reason why you can't do this without them, it just takes a bit more work.

Comment: Also, 2010 supports `std::function` and `std::bind`.  Boost is better, and 2012 is better still, but it's there in 2010.  Try it out with a simple program to find out what's there and what's not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reuse the command processing framework you've set up to send commands *as answers* from the worker thread back to the client? It would require turning your framework into a more generic messaging framework, but perhaps it's already fit for that purpose.

The command object/struct should contain:

- an id of the command (necessary for answering back its completion status)
- optionally an issuer id (the client who sent the command).

  You need to set command queues back from the worker thread to the clients. One queue per client would be ideal, but if you have a client id embedded in your command object/structure, you should be able to use that id to tag the answers, so that it helps clients filtering their messages from a global answer queue. 
  You also need to add in the clients a function to check the answer queue at idle time, and process the answer to update the UI state. Many UI frameworks (if not all) support that possibility, so it should not be a problem. Another option is to hook up the queue to the UI event system if your UI or framework support it.

Note that there are lock free queue algorithms for 1 writer to 1 reader configurations, which could be interesting for individual answer queues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `concurrent_queue<std::function<void()>>`, then check this queue on the main thread for functions.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting option, however it's unlikely to meet my needs. I don't have ownership of the main thread, only the worker thread - this is because the component I'm developing is consumed by other teams / products. They have the main thread, which they could be doing anything with, i.e. Windows message loop, never ending loop, etc. etc. etc.